# Swift 2 jSON Call can throw but it is not marked with try

Tags: ios, json, xcode7, swift2

yesterday i updated to El Capitan beta 2 and Xcode 7 - beta is mandatory. So i updated my app to Swift 2 and new error comes to the json string. This is my code :

`let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary`

and this is the error: `Call can throw , but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a `do/catch` block as this is the preferred way of reporting errors, rather than using `NSError`:

```
do {
   let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
   // use jsonData
} catch {
    // report error
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, anyway this doesn't fix the issue :\

Comment: i changed with  let `jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary` and it works

Comment: @Droppy I'm aware that we can't force unwrap because `JSONObjectWithData` must `throw` something. But for learning purposes if we used `try!`, won't that just unwrap and throw and crash if it fails — just like forced unwrapping? I mean in such a situation would `try!` have any functional advantage? I am asking this because if I ever had to force crashing, I could either just go for forced-unwrapping or `try!`—seemingly with no added benefits

Answer (score 2):

Put the term "try!" after the equals sign.

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
```

No need then, for the catch clause, or for a throws declaration. Doing so would be a good idea if you cannot truly recover from a failure there.

For more information, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options:nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary
println("== \(UserDict)")
```